# How to programmatically update a ServiceReference into an WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm currently work on an application(WPF) which consume a wcf service on IIS. When the time come to publish or make my application runnable, i think it was very nice to update this application every time when the wcf service is update too!

How can i currently in the development implement such functionality?

Comment: In general, this is not a good idea. Your application needs to be synchronized with the version of the service that it will be using. More importantly, updating a service reference is effectively rewriting some of the code of your application (in the Reference.cs). This means you should probably test  your application again at that time. Updating the service reference "automatically" would mean you won't have control over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a very good reason to want to have this functionality. If that's the case it's very easy to get TFS to automatically do a build of your app everytime the web service is updated, just be selecting what you want building in the build wizard. If however you want to update the service referencephalitis, then that is going to involve some XAML build script wizardry as you have to tell team build to deploy and then after that update the service reference .

Answer (score 0):

You can use svctool.exe to generate the service client implementation. This is what visual studio uses behind the scenes. [See here for svcutil.exe documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)